# How do I wire a light with only two white wires and nothing else?

Tags: electrical

I bought a light that is labeled a night light.  When I opened the box I found that it has a red and black wire that lead to some sort of electrical component which I believe is related to the remote control.  The only two wires that exit this component are white.  There were no instructions at all.  I'm assuming it goes to a ceiling box from the way the bottom of the light looks.  How would I wire this into a ceiling box? Can this be wired with a plug instead?[image: night light fixture]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. That blob in the cord is heat shrink tubing, probably around some sort of voltage converter. What was the light advertised as? LED? Do you have a manufacturer/part number?

Comment: Nothing that I am seeing there looks safe to connect to a box in the US. Nor would it be safe to put a plug on the wires. Where did you get that? What area are you in?

Comment: Find this item sold somewhere online and show us the link, so we can help you figure it out. Failing that; throw it away. I see no provision to secure it to any type of junction box that I'm familiar with. It'd better *not* be 120v 'cause it looks like it just screws to a stud...

Comment: I can't speak for the US, but here in NZ it's common to screw fittings directly to the wall/ceiling (generally on a batten, with the wire running through a hole in the batten). Looks like you undo both screws on the side, then screw that plate to the wall. Ballast/driver goes inside the can of the fitting.

Answer (score 1):

Strange it came with no documentation.

The backward UR is an underwriters laboratories recognized component marking. It appears to have a C before it and a US after it.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UL_(safety_organization)#Recognized_Component_Mark

That doesn't mean the whole assembly is UL approved but it means that part has been tested.

Either send it back and get a refund, or contact the company that sold it to you for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that it's meant for 120VAC, then just connect the two white wires from the light to the white and black wires from your home wiring. (I'm assuming you're in the USA)

Since that box is likely just an AC to DC power supply, the "polarity" of the wires shouldn't matter.

I'd also connect the ground wire to the metal frame to make sure the lamp is grounded.

It looks like in order to mount it in a ceiling box, you'd take off the 2 screws on the side to free up the metal bracket, then screw that bracket into the ceiling box, and then use the two screws on the side to reattach the lamp to the bracket.

While you could put a plug on the end of the white wires, it doesn't look like it was meant to be used that way, and the power supply may not be meant to be exposed where it could come into direct contact by people. It's covered by heat shrink tubing, but it's hard to say what exposed wiring may be just within that heat shrink tubing. At a minimum I'd want to use a 3 wire grounded cord to ground the light housing.

I'll add though, that unless the device meets US safety regulations (being sold by a major retailer and having a UL or CE listing would be a good sign), I wouldn't connect it to my home's wiring since some cheap imported electronics sometimes fail catastrophically and [can lead to fire](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2406185/Fake-Apple-Cheap-phone-chargers-burn-house.html). Note that a UL or CE listed label by itself is no guarantee of safety since cheap imports sometimes [use fake labels](http://www.reliableplant.com/Read/17621/how-to-tell-a-real-vs-fake-ul-mark-on-electronics).